# Remote Powershell Eventing

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a master powershell console and a few remote machines. What I'm trying to accomplish is that the remote machines will be waiting for some events created at the master end. How do I accomplish this ? Pls help me out with a working example so that I will just do a wait-event on all the remote machines, and when all these machines receive an event, say a message from the master, the wait-event gets suspended.

I tried out the custom events on one machine and it worked as well:

```
PS > Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier Custom.Event `
>>     -Action { Write-Host "Received Event" }
>>

PS > $null = New-Event Custom.Event
Received Event
```

How do I do this remotely ? I just want a wait-event on remote machines, and on an event(on a message received), the wait-event should terminate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849967.aspx

Check the documentation on the -Forward parameter, and look at Example 1.